# TUSKit iOS 8: ERROR: connection requested new body stream, which is currently not supported

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using TUSKit for iOS and tus.io for our API. After setting up tus.io and configuring the example project for TUSKit

```
<TUSResumableUpload.m:(115)> Finished upload to `PATH/videos/uploads/15/` for fingerprint assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=30C691FA-5866-4498-82CB-E95FB600BD74&ext=mp4
2015-04-07 01:46:36.397 TUSKit[207:8879] url: PATH/videos/uploads/15/
2015-04-07 01:46:36.410 TUSKit[207:8879] <TUSResumableUpload.m:(157)> ERROR: connection requested new body stream, which is currently not supported
```

**the snippet**

```
- (NSInputStream *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection needNewBodyStream:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    TUSLog(@"ERROR: connection requested new body stream, which is currently not supported");
    return nil;
}
```

in `TUSResumableUpload.m`

is where we are getting the error, I'm just not sure why

the uploads on the server are started, but empty.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

There was a bug in the API with the redirects which caused the `TUSKit` to fail to finish the upload.

And then we had to change the way binary data was received in order to start getting data in our files.